# Quickblox JS SDK notifyOccupants on dialog creation

Tags: javascript, sdk, quickblox

I use this code retrieve from http://quickblox.com/developers/Javascript.

> My SDK info: /* QuickBlox JavaScript SDK - v2.1.4 - 2016-07-19 */

```
function notifyOccupants(dialogOccupants, newDialogId) {
  dialogOccupants.forEach(function(itemOccupanId, i, arr) {
    if (itemOccupanId != currentUser.id) {
      var msg = {
        type: 'chat',
        extension: {
          notification_type: 1,
          _id: newDialogId,
        }, 
      };
      QB.chat.send(itemOccupanId, msg);
    }
  });
}
```

When I execute this function it is returning always:

```
"quickblox.min.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined".
```

Someone can help?

Answer (score 0):

As said in their [tutorial](https://quickblox.com/developers/Web_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Guide:_Getting_Started_with_Chat_API),
you have to initialize QB object before you can use it.

Ensure you have this lines in your code:

```
QB.createSession({login: user.login, password: user.pass}, function(err, res) {
  if (res) {
    QB.chat.connect({userId: user.id, password: user.pass}, function(err, roster) {
```

and check you code is inside `connect` function callback,
to be sure your code will run only after QB initialization.

Comment: I initialized quickblox using this QB.init(data.token, quickblox.appId), i create quickblox user session in my server, and i insure that exist an session. After I call create a new dialog with success.

Answer (score 0):

My code:

```
var usersIds = [];
usersIds.push(user);

var params = {
    type: 3,
    occupants_ids: usersIds
};

console.log("Creating a dialog with params: " + JSON.stringify(params));

QB.chat.dialog.create(params, function (err, createdDialog) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        errorCallback();
    } else {
        console.log("Dialog " + createdDialog._id + " created with users: " + usersIds);

        // save dialog to local storage
        var dialogId = createdDialog._id;
        QuickbloxConfig.dialogs[dialogId] = createdDialog;

        QuickbloxConfig.currentDialog = createdDialog;
//
//                    self.joinToNewDialogAndShow(createdDialog);

        self.notifyOccupants(createdDialog.occupants_ids, createdDialog._id, 1);

        //self.triggerDialog(createdDialog._id);

        successCallback();

    }
});
```

Its only fail when I call self.notifyOccupants(createdDialog.occupants_ids, createdDialog._id, 1);

Comment: where do you set `self`?

Comment: My app is on angularjs, I create a service, and I use var self = this; to access other functions in the service.

Comment: Are you sure   `QB.chat.connect` already finish without error?

Comment: My steps:
- QB.init(token, quickblox.appId);
If I initialize with token, i have that make this "QB.chat.connect({userId: user.id, password: user.pass}, function (err, roster)" call?
I try this but i receive: angular.js:11270 TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined